# Working with Dialogs in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, dialog

I'm working with some custom dialog classes that I've built for an android application.  When one of these dialog classes are called it displays the dialog, the user makes changes to widgets in the dialog, then those changes effect the calling activity once the dialog is dismissed.

I've developed a few work arounds to get this functioning...but I like neat code, and all the work arounds that I've toyed with are just not attractive to me (static variables, return statements, etc).  So I thought perhaps I could put a few statements in the OnResume or on ReStart methods of my calling activity to do the necessary work.  Nothing happens when I dismiss the dialog though, so I don't believe that any of the OverRide methods for an activity's life cycle are called when a dialog is dismissed (even though at first appearances OnPause is called when the dialog is started).

I looked through the Andoid docs and read that I could interface dialog in my custom dialog class and use/override various methods there.  That just seems like a cannonball to kill a fly in my opinion (especially since I all ready have a work around in place that functions just fine).

So, basically I was wondering what method is called (either from the dialog or from the activity that started the dialog) to restart the activity that called the dialog.  <-- that sentence makes no sense to me...   Let me describe with a diagram (I can give pseudo code if entirely necessary; but I don't see how that would help anymore)

Calling Activity creates the dialog--> (then the calling activity gets grayed out via some method) --> dialog displays --> blah blah-->  dialog gets dismissed --> (the calling activity resumes via some method)

The two methods above that are in parenthesis, what are they? (the latter is especially relevant to my interests)  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how it goes about greying out the background but there are a few listeners you can implement and put the relevant code in there, the OnDismissListener, OnCancelListener and OnShowListener (API level 8 required).

Example (same syntax for the other listeners)

```
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // do stuff 

        }
    });
```